# « Investiguer » ou « enquêter »

Tags: vocabulaire, anglicismes

Est-ce qu'« *investiguer* » est un anglicisme? La même question s'applique à tout autre mot de la même famille comme *investigation*.

Étant donné que chaque pays, ou presque, dans la francophonie a son propre dictionnaire, j'ai l'impression qu'aucune « autorité » n'a pour fonction de décider de ce qui est un « anglicisme » et de ce qui n'en est pas un.

Où puis-je me renseigner sur le sujet?

Comment: Puisqu'on en est à rechercher ce qui est juste, français ou anglais, j'aimerais juste préciser à la personne qui a posé la question relative à "investiguer" qu'il aurait été préférable de dire, à la place de "...est en charge de décider qu'est-ce qui est un « anglicisme » et qu'est-ce qui n'en est pas un.", ...est en charge de décider ce qui est un anglicisme et ce qui n'en est pas un...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En terme de langue, il n'y a pas d'autorité 100%, parce que la langue n'est pas un objet mécanique. C'est plutôt un espèce d'écosystème où de nouvelles interactions, espèces etc. apparaissent et disparaissent constamment. La limite entre «anglicisme» et «emprunt» est difficile à démarquer précisément. Personnellement je crois qu'il est raisonnable de parler d'anglicisme si le mot n'accomplit rien de nouveau en français.

*Investigation* n'est pas nouveau: il a été introduit par Jean-Jacques Rousseau au sens de «Recherche minutieuse, systématiquement poursuivie, sur quelque chose.» ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/investigation)), plus précisément en sciences. Au simple sens d'«enquête», toutefois, c'est à mon avis un anglicisme, et *investiguer*, que mon Petit Robert date de 1954 «sous l'influence de l'anglais» (i.e. une [dérivation régressive](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9rivation_r%C3%A9gressive)) en est presque toujours un, mais j'avoue que c'est mon opinion personnelle: comme je l'ai dit (enfin, sous-entendu) plus tôt, la notion d'anglicisme n'est jamais loin du purisme linguistique, qui n'est pas exactement une approche scientifique de la langue...

Comment: Le lien vers TLF est très intéressant. Je comprend qu'il n'y aie pas d'autorité officielle, mais un site web avec autant d'information peut devenir une autorité implicite. Merci!

Comment: Je dirais que c'est plus compliqué que ça. Les dictionnaires tentent de refléter l'usage de la langue, surtout l'usage écrit, mais l'usage en pratique ne reflète pas toujours les critiques, et bien des gens aiment traiter les dictionnaires comme une autorité absolue, alors que ce n'est pas le but d'aucun éditeur de dictionnaire moderne (même si les départements publicitaires approchent le problème différemment!). Tout jugement sur la langue n'est jamais qu'une forme d'appel à l'autorité susceptible de s'avérer fallacieux.